# Vue3 CLI keeps asking about slow internet connection

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs3, hadoop-yarn

During an E2E test process I automatically install Vue3 via Vue CLI, the exact command is:

```
npx --yes @vue/cli create vue3 --packageManager npm -n -i '{"useConfigFiles":true,"plugins":{"@vue/cli-plugin-babel":{},"@vue/cli-plugin-typescript":{"classComponent":false,"useTsWithBabel":true},"@vue/cli-plugin-pwa":{},"@vue/cli-plugin-router":{"historyMode":true},"@vue/cli-plugin-vuex":{},"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint":{"config":"prettier","lintOn":["save"]}},"vueVersion":"3"}'
```

The problem is, that during the process, this question keeps coming:

```
?  Your connection to the default yarn registry seems to be slow.
   Use https://registry.npmmirror.com for faster installation? (Y/n)
```

Since it is waiting for an input, the build fails. How can I deactivate this prompt?

Comment: You can try installing Vue3 through NPM/Yarn instead of Vue-CLI.

Comment: It's a requirement to install via Vue CLI, so that's no option for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by looking at the Vue CLI source code. If you run the create command with the registry parameter, or you can set the environment variable VUE_CLI_TEST to avoid that prompt. Since I don't know what other implications setting the variable has, I run with the registry command.
Here's the code from src, `shouldUseTaobao` is the function that is responsible for the prompt:

```js
    const args = minimist(process.argv, {
      alias: {
        r: 'registry'
      }
    })

    let registry
    if (args.registry) {
      registry = args.registry
    } else if (!process.env.VUE_CLI_TEST && await shouldUseTaobao(this.bin)) {
      registry = registries.taobao
    } else {
      try {
        if (scope) {
          registry = (await execa(this.bin, ['config', 'get', scope + ':registry'])).stdout
        }
        if (!registry || registry === 'undefined') {
          registry = (await execa(this.bin, ['config', 'get', 'registry'])).stdout
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // Yarn 2 uses `npmRegistryServer` instead of `registry`
        registry = (await execa(this.bin, ['config', 'get', 'npmRegistryServer'])).stdout
      }
    }
```